# Detect When SKPhysicsBodies Overlap

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two SKSpriteNodes, one is a thin vertical rectangle dividing the screen and the other is a ball bouncing from side to side. When the ball touches the divider a contact is triggered as expected. However, while the ball is moving through the divider I would like to continue to trigger the contact function for each frame.

How can I detect when two SKPhysicsBody objects overlap? I had some success using the intersectsNode() function but that uses the sprite's image size, which doesn't always match the physics body outline so I'm looking for an alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: Have you looked at the [`allContactedBodies`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/allContactedBodies) method?

Comment: @rickster Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for! Guess I missed that when reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`allContactedBodies`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/allContactedBodies) method in the docs.